# strcpy access private object in class

Tags: c++, json, private, strcpy

I'm reading data from a file in JSON format, and I want to put the values in the objects `password_c` and `apiKeyValue` members:

```
class Configuration {
private:
    char password_c[32];
    char apiKeyValue_c[20];
public:
    String get_ApiKeyValue();
    void set_ApiKeyValue(char* apiKeyValue);

    String get_Password();
    void set_Password(char* password);
};

String Configuration::get_Password() {
    return password_c;
}

void Configuration::set_Password(char* password ) {
    strcpy(password_c, password); 
}  

String Configuration::get_ApiKeyValue() {
    return  apiKeyValue_c;
}

void Configuration::set_ApiKeyValue(char* apiKeyValue) {
    strcpy(apiKeyValue_c, apiKeyValue); 
}

bool Configuracao::loadFile() {

    if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to mount file system");
        while(true);
    }
  
    StaticJsonDocument<700> doc; 
    File file = SPIFFS.open(("/config.json"), "r");
    if (!file){
        Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
        //return;
    }

    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, file);
    if (error) {
        Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
        Serial.println(error.f_str());
        return -1;
    } 

    strcpy(password_c, doc["password"]); // I belive that it can't work, but it work. password_c is private
    strcpy(apiKeyValue_c, doc["apiKeyValue"]);

    // - Test
    Serial.println(get_Password()); //value ok!
    Serial.println(password_c);     //value ok! 
    file.close();
}
```

The commands work inside the method that reads the JSON file, but I thought this would not be possible since both members are private.

I can print the result of `password_c` and `apiKeyValue_c` right after `strcpy()`.

```cpp
Serial.println(get_Password()); // using the method
Serial.println(password_c); // direct (I don't know why this way works, as they are private.
```

I imagined that I would have to implement set methods to access these objects.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: the fields are private to the methods, loadFIle is a method of the class

Comment: On an unrelated note, using `std::string` is (almost always) better than `char []` for storing strings.

Comment: The code, as shown, will not compile, since there is no class `Configuracao` defined, and the `Configuration` class that is shown has no `loadFile()` method declared. Please don't make up code, copy/paste your *real* code.

Answer (score 0):

Code that is **outside** of a class, and is not declared to be a `friend` of that class, cannot access that class's `private` members.  But, code that in **inside** of the class's own methods can freely access the class's `private` members.  A class would be fairly useless if it couldn't access its own data.

So, in this case, assuming you meant for `Configuracao` to be `Configuration` instead, and that you meant to declare a `loadFile()` method in the `Configuration` class, then `Configuration::loadFile()` can access `Configuration`'s private members without restriction.  But, any code that is *using* a `Configuration` object (and is not a `friend` of `Configuration`) would not be able to access the private members at all, and would have to use its public getters/setters instead.